# In R, mark an ID's rows after an event, but not before it

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

**Background**

I've got this `R` dataframe, `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","b", "c","c","c"),
                event = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-08-21","2011-12-23","2014-12-31","2013-03-14","2013-04-07","2014-07-14")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's got three people (`ID`'s), along with a 0/1 indicator of whether an `event` of interest occurs, and an `event_date` when that event occurred.

**The Problem / Question**

I want to edit the `event` column so that for each `ID` where *any* row has `event = 1`, all rows chronologically (by `event_date`) after the first `event = 1` are also marked `event = 1`.

In other words, I'd like something that looks like this:

```
df_want <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","b", "c","c","c"),
                 event = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-08-21","2011-12-23","2014-12-31","2013-03-14","2013-04-07","2014-07-14")),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Which would look like so:

[image]

As you can see, for `ID`'s `a` and `c`, the event column now shows `event = 1` for that ID's rows after the date of the first `event = 1`. For ID `b`, nothing happens, as they do not have any `event = 1`.

Note that in the "real" dataset I'm doing this procedure on, ID's generally have many more rows after their first `event = 1`, so a solution would need to apply to all of them. (I add this caveat since `ID`'s `a` and `c` only have one row after their `event = 1`.)

**What I've tried**

I have some code that will apply `event = 1` to everything, but that obviously doesn't get me very far:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(exposed = 1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for `group_by` and more importantly `?cummax`

Answer (score 2):

We could first group and then use `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(event = cumsum(event == 1))
```

```
  ID    event event_date
  <chr> <int> <date>    
1 a         0 2011-01-01
2 a         1 2011-08-21
3 a         1 2011-12-23
4 b         0 2014-12-31
5 c         0 2013-03-14
6 c         1 2013-04-07
7 c         1 2014-07-14
```